# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins (spring framework dependencies)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I opened IntelliJ this morning and see this. No changes have been made to the code. I deleted my local .m2 repository and re-downloaded all my dependencies. I'm still getting the same issue. Why are my basic spring libraries not being imported?

[image]

**Error:**

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 17 source files to C:\Users\martin\Documents\Web Projects\home.office\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/UserController.java:[45,45] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.Users
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/RequestController.java:[139,54] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.RequestDO> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.RequestDO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/RequestController.java:[140,49] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.Users
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/RequestController.java:[155,54] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.RequestDO> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.RequestDO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/RequestController.java:[157,49] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.Users
[INFO] 5 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:43 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-24T11:12:29+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/255M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/UserController.java:[45,45] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.Users
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/RequestController.java:[139,54] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.RequestDO> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.RequestDO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/RequestController.java:[140,49] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.Users
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/RequestController.java:[155,54] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.RequestDO> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.RequestDO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/geo/app/controller/RequestController.java:[157,49] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<geo.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to geo.app.entity.Users
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Try to run the mvn clean install from command line, intellij sometime behaves weird if you do not import the changes in pom.xml

Comment: I've tried and I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: Did you "Reimport All Maven Projects" on the Maven sidebar in IntelliJ? This should sync the pom and the module dependency settings.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I pressed Ctrl + Shift + A and searched "Reimport All Maven Projects".

Comment: Sorry. I spoke too soon. There are still some missing dependencies resulting in the same build failure. I'll just keep trying to re-import until it works..

Comment: I'm continuing my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997655/incompatible-types-java-util-optionalxyz-app-entity-users-cannot-be-converted