# incompatible types: java.util.Optional<xyz.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to Users (Springboot compilation error)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm getting an incompatible types error message at the following line in my spring-boot application:

```
RequestDO request = requestRepository.findOne(requestModel.getRequestId());
Users employee = usersRepository.findOne(request.getUsers().getId());
```

I have not experienced this error in this context before. My app has been running successfully since its first production build about one month ago.

**Build failure:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project tmt: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/xyz/app/controller/UserController.java:[45,45] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<xyz.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to xyz.app.entity.Users
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/xyz/app/controller/RequestController.java:[139,54] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<xyz.app.entity.RequestDO> cannot be converted to xyz.app.entity.RequestDO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/xyz/app/controller/RequestController.java:[140,49] incompatible types: java.util.app<xyz.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to xyz.app.entity.Users
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/xyz/app/controller/RequestController.java:[155,54] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<v.app.entity.RequestDO> cannot be converted to xyz.app.entity.RequestDO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/martin/Documents/Web Projects/home.office/src/main/java/xyz/app/controller/RequestController.java:[157,49] incompatible types: java.util.Optional<xyz.app.entity.Users> cannot be converted to xyz.app.entity.Users
```

I have made no code changes since I've last successfully re-built my project. This leads me to believe there has been a recent change in the springframework Maven dependency that has caused my code to break. Is it possible to test this by reverting to an older snapshot in my pom.xml? Also, what could be causing the error?

**pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xyz.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-freemarker-email</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Which versions of spring and spring-boot do you use? Are you really using a snapshot version? If so, do this only if you want to test bleeding edge. Reverting to an older snapshot won't probably work. Of course you can revert to an older release version.

Comment: ``<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>``

What should I set the version to?

Comment: Should I include a different repository? I'm typically pulling from the snapshot repo.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Isn't the message clear? findOne() returns an Optional<Users>, which is not the same type as Users. If you want stable dependencies, why do you use snapshots? And if you want to be on the edge by using a snapshot, why don't you adapt your code to the new release of the snapshot?

Comment: Because all I know is that I haven't changed a single line of code and everything was working until last night. The issue was some kind of dependency change which I can't identify. So  my question is what is the alternative that will allow me to return my previously stable build? With all due respect, suggested solutions should address the solution, not my programming habits.

Comment: You have never had a stable build if you only use snapshots. Snapshots are in current development, so that means also APIs can change (which it did in your case). If you want to have a stable build, then use releases (you can see the latest released version on the Spring Boot homepage). If you don't know the difference between snapshots and releases in the Maven world, then have a look at a Maven tutorial (e.g. https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_a_SNAPSHOT_version)

Comment: Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980740/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-data-class-cast-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue using 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, so unless you're experimenting with some low-level spring boot features, change the version to `1.5.2.RELEASE`

Comment: I couldn't reach the result......

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I still haven't got the answer.
But there is a solution. May be it help you.

[Source option 5 is no longer supported](https://github.com/jflex-de/jflex/issues/400)